# How can I make GitHub Actions work with PRs made by external contributors?

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request, github-secret

My GitHub actions [depend](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-proxy/blob/99af20882501e5b6a85be96e5757f2524c1f4342/.github/workflows/integration.yaml#L3-L8) on some GitHub secrets that I set in my [repo](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-proxy):

[image: GitHub secrets]

CI works when I push a commit:

https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-proxy/actions/runs/1958606928

But it fails when an external contributor makes a PR from their forked version of the repo:

https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-proxy/runs/4581619160

The execution fails because of this error:

> Error: Please set MNEMONIC as an env variable

But the `MNEOMNIC` secret is there. Why doesn't it work when the GitHub Action is triggered by a PR made by an external contributor?

Comment: From what I read [here](https://github.blog/2020-08-03-github-actions-improvements-for-fork-and-pull-request-workflows/) about public and private forked repos, you can set a `pull_request_target` to run the event against the workflow and code from the base of the pull request: _This means the workflow is running from a trusted source and is given access to a read/write token as well as secrets enabling the maintainer to safely comment on or label a pull request._ However, it might not work using _push_ events.

Comment: Note that even `pull_request_target` is insecure in most cases and can compromise your secrets. But there are some ways to make it "more secure." See: [Github Actions: Preventing pwn requests](https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/)

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue without having to use `pull_request_target`?